# Using select to replace values which meet a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I like to use `Select` statements to clean my data. Usually I will use the `Select` to exclude data from the next stage of my analysis/calculation

For example here is some pretend data with some outliers.

```
SomeFunction[A_,ω_, a0_, t_] := A Cos[ω t+t ] + a0
SomeData = 
Table[
        {
            t, (*Index or x ordinate*)
            Round[SomeFunction[1,0.123, 1.2345, t] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,0.2]],0.001], (* "measured" data *)
            Round[SomeFunction[1,0.123, 1.2345, t],0.001] (* true data, unoised*)
        },
        {t, 0,10, 0.5}
    ];

 SomeData = 
{{0., 2.452, 2.234}, {0.5, 2.529, 2.081}, {1., 1.538, 1.667}, {1.5, 
      1.334, 1.121}, {2., 0.6, 0.609}, {2.5, 0.616, 0.29}, {3., 0.149, 
      0.26}, {3.5, 0.408, 0.53}, {4., 1.141, 1.016}, {4.5, 1.696, 
      1.569}, {5., 1.833, 2.019}, {5.5, 2.574, 2.229}, {6., 2.1, 
      2.133}, {6.5, 1.773, 1.761}, {7., 1.495, 1.227}, {7.5, 0.889, 
  0.696}, {8., 0.786, 0.33}, {8.5, 0.306, 0.242}, {9., 0.313, 
  0.458}, {9.5, 1.134, 0.913}, {10., 1.422, 1.467}}
```

The three columns are index, the "measured" data, and the expected data

To filter these out is trivial. One can do something like:
`Select[SomeData, #[[2]] - #[[3]] < 0.2 &][[1;;,{1,2}]]`
So where the "measured" or noised data differs from the "true" or noised value by some defined threshold, the rows are excluded.

However, I instead want to replace the outlier values with some other value. The reason being that I want to preserve the structure of my data set, and by replacing the outlier points with some ludicrous value, I can filter these out right at the end of my evaluation.

The above `Select` statement filters rows with the index `t= 2.5 , 5.5, 7, 8, 9.5`. I would want to instead replace the value with `999999` for example so the output would be

```
{{1.`, 1.538`}, {2.`, 0.6`}, {2.5`, 999999`}, {3.`, 0.149`}, {3.5`, 
  0.408`}, {4.`, 1.141`}, {4.5`, 1.696`}, {5.`, 1.833`}, {5.5`, 
  999999`}, {6.`, 2.1`}, {6.5`, 1.773`}, {7`, 999999`}, {7.5`, 
  0.889`}, {8`, 999999`}, {8.5`, 0.306`}, {9.`, 0.313`}, {9.5`, 
  999999`}, {10.`, 1.422`}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match your desired output, but it matches your description I think?  Does `SomeData /. {x : {a_, b_, c_} /; b - c < 0.2 :> Most@x, x : {a_, b_, c_} /; b - c >= 0.2 :> {a, 999999}}` give you what you want?

Comment: Your rule replacement is elegant.  I was trying to figure out how to get that to work with ReplacePart and was stumped.

Comment: @march you should also post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[clip];
clip[δ_, repl_: 9999][{a_, b_, c_}] := 
    {a, Clip[b, {-∞, c + δ - 2 $MachineEpsilon}, {-∞, repl}]};

Map[clip[.2]] @ SomeData
```

> {{0., 9999}, {0.5, 9999}, {1., 1.538}, {1.5, 9999}, {2., 0.6}, {2.5, 
>         9999}, {3., 0.149}, {3.5, 0.408}, {4., 1.141}, {4.5, 1.696}, {5., 
>         1.833}, {5.5, 9999}, {6., 2.1}, {6.5, 1.773}, {7., 9999}, {7.5, 
>         0.889}, {8., 9999}, {8.5, 0.306}, {9., 0.313}, {9.5, 9999}, {10., 
>         1.422}}

```
 Map[clip[.1, Null]] @ SomeData
```

> {{0., Null}, {0.5, Null}, {1., 1.538}, {1.5, Null}, {2., 0.6}, {2.5, 
>     Null}, {3., 0.149}, {3.5, 0.408}, {4., Null}, {4.5, Null}, {5., 
>     1.833}, {5.5, Null}, {6., 2.1}, {6.5, 1.773}, {7., Null}, {7.5, 
>     Null}, {8., Null}, {8.5, 0.306}, {9., 0.313}, {9.5, Null}, {10., 
>     1.422}}

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this do what you want:

```
Block[{outlierPositions = 
   Flatten[Position[SomeData, #] & /@ 
     Select[SomeData, ! (#[[2]] - #[[3]] < 0.2) &], 1], 
  replacements},
 replacements = Append[#, 2] & /@ outlierPositions;
 ReplacePart[SomeData, replacements -> 999999][[;; , {1, 2}]]
 ]

(*{{0., 999999}, {0.5, 999999}, {1., 1.538}, {1.5, 999999}, {2., 
  0.6}, {2.5, 999999}, {3., 0.149}, {3.5, 0.408}, {4., 1.141}, {4.5, 
  1.696}, {5., 1.833}, {5.5, 999999}, {6., 2.1}, {6.5, 1.773}, {7., 
  999999}, {7.5, 0.889}, {8., 999999}, {8.5, 0.306}, {9., 
  0.313}, {9.5, 999999}, {10., 1.422}}*)
```

This code inverts your "good criteria" to find outliers and then uses ReplacePart to do what you wanted.

Comment: This is a nice solution, +1. I will accept kglr's answer purely on the basis that it is less lines of code. What I do like about yours is that it is more transparent as to to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Using replacement rules:

```
SomeData /. x : {a_, b_, c_} :> If[b - c < 0.2, Most@x, {a, 999999}]
(* {{0., 999999}, {0.5, 999999}, {1., 1.538}, {1.5, 999999},
    {2., 0.6}, {2.5, 999999}, {3., 0.149}, {3.5, 0.408},
    {4., 1.141}, {4.5, 1.696}, {5., 1.833}, {5.5, 999999},
    {6., 2.1}, {6.5, 1.773}, {7., 999999}, {7.5, 0.889},
    {8., 999999}, {8.5, 0.306}, {9., 0.313}, {9.5, 999999}, {10., 1.422}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, although I have already accepted an answer I thought your solution was neat and deserved at least an upvote!